# .NET to Google Analytics timezone conversion

Tags: .net, .net-core, google-analytics, timezone

Timezone in .NET Core has a different Id that that of Google Analytics.
For example, in .NET Core it is

`Central Europe Standard Time`

and in Google Analytics it is

`Europe/Prague`

Is there a way how to convert from one to another? What could a solution for the conversion look like?

Comment: If the list of Timezone IDs differ, you could map it in your .net application.

Comment: @Phael thank you, yes, if there is no other way, I will add mapping into the .net application

Comment: Your question ins unclear What google analytics in .net are you talking about exactly?   please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Google Analytics is using IANA time zones, which are supported on .NET Core on Linux/MacOS, and on Windows via TimeZoneConverter library, or on any platform without a library using .NET 6.  See the dup link for further info.